# Update tabbar when nothing to save

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using tab-bar to tabify my work in Emacs, and so far I found tabbar-ruler that basically adds an indicator to show when a file is modified.
It doesn't work by itself, apparently.

I added some pieces of code that let tabbar know the file is modified,
but it doesn't work when I revert my work.
I need some hook, if possible, to let emacs know that upon reaching a "don't have to save" state, it will udpate the tabbar.

This is the code so far:

```
(defadvice tabbar-buffer-tab-label (after fixup_tab_label_space_and_flag activate)
(setq ad-return-value
     (if (and (buffer-modified-p (tabbar-tab-value tab))
              (buffer-file-name (tabbar-tab-value tab)))
         (concat " " (concat ad-return-value " "))
       (concat " " (concat ad-return-value " ")))))

;; Called each time the modification state of the buffer changed.
(defun er/modification-state-change ()
    (tabbar-set-template tabbar-current-tabset nil)
    (tabbar-display-update))
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'er/modification-state-change)

;; First-change-hook is called BEFORE the change is made.
(defun er/on-buffer-modification ()
    (set-buffer-modified-p t)
    (er/modification-state-change))
(add-hook 'first-change-hook 'er/on-buffer-modification)

;; Retrieve original state after revert is made.
(defun er/on-buffer-revert ()
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
    (er/modification-state-change))
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'er/on-buffer-revert)
```

The er/on-buffer-revert function is my attempt to at least reach a reverted buffer state.
Doesn't work either.

The first piece of code, btw, is just to add an additional space tabbar doesn't originaly have.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this several years ago, but here's a working example that properly supports reverts.  Note that it supports tabbar state correctly for the following situations:

- buffer reverts
- undo back to last saved state
- changing the text to match what it was before the last save

```lisp
    (defun my-ignore-buffer-p ()
      (not (buffer-file-name)))

    (setq my-buffer-hashes (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
    (defun my-set-buffer-hash ()
      (puthash (current-buffer) (buffer-hash) my-buffer-hashes))
    (defun my-get-buffer-hash ()
      (gethash (current-buffer) my-buffer-hashes))
    (defun my-buffer-hash-changed-p ()
      (not (string= (buffer-hash) (my-get-buffer-hash))))

    ;; Hook save and change events to show modified buffers in tabbar
    (defun on-saving-buffer ()
      (tabbar-set-template tabbar-current-tabset nil)
      (tabbar-display-update))
    (defun on-modifying-buffer ()
      (unless (my-ignore-buffer-p)
        (my-set-buffer-hash)
        (set-buffer-modified-p (buffer-modified-p))
        (tabbar-set-template tabbar-current-tabset nil)
        (tabbar-display-update)))
    (defun after-modifying-buffer (begin end length)
      (unless (my-ignore-buffer-p)
        (set-buffer-modified-p (my-buffer-hash-changed-p))
        (tabbar-set-template tabbar-current-tabset nil)
        (tabbar-display-update)))

    (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'on-saving-buffer)
    (add-hook 'first-change-hook 'on-modifying-buffer)
    (add-hook 'after-change-functions 'after-modifying-buffer)
```